# Error deploying Grails application - Beginner

Tags: java, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

I am having issues deploying a Grails application. Everything works in the local test environment.

ERROR

> [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error
>   initializing the application: Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property
>   'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property
>   'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while
>   extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Exception:
>   "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/prodDb.lock.db
>   (Permission denied)"; "/var/lib/tomcat7/prodDb.lock.db" [90031-164])
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property
>   'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property
>   'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while
>   extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Exception:
>   "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/prodDb.lock.db
>   (Permission denied)"; "/var/lib/tomcat7/prodDb.lock.db" [90031-164])
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

BUILD CONFIG FILE :

```
// locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config;
// config files can be ConfigSlurper scripts, Java properties files, or classes
// in the classpath in ConfigSlurper format

// grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]

// if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
//    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
// }

grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination
grails.mime.file.extensions = true // enables the parsing of file extensions from URLs into the request format
grails.mime.use.accept.header = false
grails.mime.types = [
    all:           '*/*',
    atom:          'application/atom+xml',
    css:           'text/css',
    csv:           'text/csv',
    form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
    js:            'text/javascript',
    json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
    rss:           'application/rss+xml',
    text:          'text/plain',
    xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]

// URL Mapping Cache Max Size, defaults to 5000
//grails.urlmapping.cache.maxsize = 1000

// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']

// The default codec used to encode data with ${}
grails.views.default.codec = "none" // none, html, base64
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
// enable Sitemesh preprocessing of GSP pages
grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = true
// scaffolding templates configuration
grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'

// Set to false to use the new Grails 1.2 JSONBuilder in the render method
grails.json.legacy.builder = false
// enabled native2ascii conversion of i18n properties files
grails.enable.native2ascii = true
// packages to include in Spring bean scanning
grails.spring.bean.packages = []
// whether to disable processing of multi part requests
grails.web.disable.multipart=false

// request parameters to mask when logging exceptions
grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

// configure auto-caching of queries by default (if false you can cache individual queries with 'cache: true')
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = false

environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.serverURL = "http://100.117.40.30:8080/MyApp"
    }
}

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

**UPDATE**

DATASOURCE.GROVVY

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should actually share your `DataSource.groovy`. Looks like there is a permission issue trying to access a file (or file db) `/var/lib/tomcat7/prodDb.lock.db`.

Comment: I have updated the post with `DataSource.groovy`

Comment: Yes app is looking for an h2 DB named prodDb. Replace that section under production environment with an actual DB you have in prod or with a DataSource or with a JNDI name.

Comment: Btw, if you are not cognizant of it yet, but you can use grails run-app to work in dev mode instead of deploying the app every time. run-app uses an embedded Tomcat at port 8080 by default.

Comment: I don't want a DB in my application for the moment. Is it possible for me to leave that blank ?

Comment: I am deploying the app in a remote server, so i must build a WAR file and deploy it. The application doesn't have a DB as yet. But i want to deploy it in the remote server.

Comment: Yes you can remove everything under `production { dataSource { .. } }` for the time being.

Comment: That sorted it. I could mark the question as correct if the solution was submitted as an Answer. Thank you loads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove your DataSource.groovy file and rebuild the WAR after doing a `grails clean`, which will disable the default file based data source

Currently it is trying to create a database on the file system but failing because you do not have the permission to do so

Comment: Doesn't work for me, if I delete DataSource.groovy I get an `hibernateBean` not found exception, is there another way to solve? Why a new created Grails project behaves so?

Comment: I didn't delete the file, but commented its content. It worked for me.