# How to avoid CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException error?

Tags: java, oracle, grails

I'm upgrading oracle from 10 to 12 and for this specific project I got this error:

```
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1460078994317> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [Oracle]!.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [Oracle]!
```

Seems like it's not recognizing the configuration I've added on DataSource:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
}
```

We are using Java 8 and we have those dependencies on the code:

```
runtime 'com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2'
runtime(group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ons', version: '10.2.0.3')
```

The thing is that it's working for the other project (that have the same structure as this one, but for some reason it's not working here)

Is there anything missing or anything I can to find the problem and solve the issue?

Comment: What are the versions of Grails and Hibernate?

Comment: Why don't you use the hibernate dialect for Oracle 12C aka org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect ?

Comment: Also make sure to use the jdbc driver that matchs exactly with your oracle version

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened for java version `1.7.0_25`. By upgrading java `1.7.0_25` to another upper version will help you to resolve the issue. Sometimes downgrade to 1.6.X also works. But upgrading is best solution.

It is **fixed in Grails 2.2.3**. But in Grails `2.2.3`, It is still broken for `OpenJDK 1.7.0_25` on Linux, `Oracle's JDK` does work though.

Credit goes to @[aeischeid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655720/aeischeid)

---

A **step by step solution** is given in this tutorial:
[Connect Grails with Oracle 11g Example Configuration](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2011/06/connect-grails-with-oracle-11g-example.html)

### Resource Link:

1. [How do I avoid 'Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database
   name [H2]!'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336107/how-do-i-avoid-could-not-determine-hibernate-dialect-for-database-name-h2)

---

### UPDATE

**Suggestion - 1:**

From [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337451/error-trying-to-run-a-grails-app), I got two suggestions, please try this 2 issues-
You need to install the [Grails H2 plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/h2). Add

```
compile ":h2:0.2.6"
```

to `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`, in the `plugins` block.

**Suggestion - 2:**

In `DataSource.groovy`, they are `case sensitive`. So please check is there anything(like `username` or others) with case mismatching.

Resource Link: [MASSIVE ERROR ON GRAILS RUN-APP](http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/grails/91155-massive-error-on-grails-run-app)

**Suggestion - 3:**

[danielnaber](https://github.com/danielnaber) gives some suggestions
`grails compile --refresh-dependencies` and/or `grails clean` might help.
You will need to configure database access in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy` (`development` for grails run-app and `production` for grails war)

**Suggestion - 4:**

From [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668991/error-deploying-grails-application-beginner)
Remove your `DataSource.groovy` file and rebuild the WAR after doing a `grails clean`, which will disable the default file based data source

Currently it is trying to create a database on the file system but failing because you do not have the permission to do so.

**Suggestion - 5:**

You can take a look in https://github.com/Netflix/Lipstick/issues/8

**Suggestion - 6:**

While you're in there you should fix the cache provider warning you're seeing too - change the value for `'cache.provider_class'` in the hibernate block to

```
   cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
```

Please give a try of 6 suggestions. Hope it can help you.

Comment: yeah, but as I said on the comments, we are using Java 8... and the grails version we are using is 2.3.9. I've already checked the links you send beforem but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Igor I have updated answer. Please have a try of 6 suggestions. I know it is crazy. I am also crazy for your solution :)